# Making explicit calls to the default Spring Cache Manager provided by SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I've enabled caching in a SpringBoot application with the @EnableCaching   and @Cacheable annotations. The cache properties are defined in the application.yaml file.

```
spring
  cache
    type=simple
```

Now I want to know if there is a way to access explicitly the cacheManager bean defined by Spring Boot(created to support the @EnableCaching annotation) without defining a new CacheManager Bean in the configuration files.

I'm basically trying to autowire the cacheManager bean defined by Spring Boot so that I can make explicit calls to it.

```
  @Autowired
  private CacheManager cacheManager;

   ...

  Cache cache = cacheManage.getCache("toto")
```

Regards

Notes: My IDE is telling me that It can't autowire the cacheManager bean

Comment: Please read through javadoc: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x//javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/EnableCaching.html

Comment: You don't have to autowire cachemanager if you want to use spring cache framework, please check https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache

Answer (score 3):

Finally, the IDE warning was wrong. I was able to autowire the cache manager bean provided by Spring Boot and I was able to call it explicitly.

Regards

Comment: I'm still getting Cache manager could not be found. How do we resolve this?